# ColdFusion 2016 Java 8 Update

Tags: java, coldfusion, java-8, coldfusion-2016

We're running ColdFusion 2016 on Windows Server 2012 R2.  I see that ColdFusion has an update (Update 5 build 303689) that requires JDK 1.8.0_121 or higher.  We are currently on 1.8.0_112.  I've opened C:\ColdFusion2016\jre\bin\javascpl.exe but I don't have an "Updates" tab like I think I should based on some googling.

I found a couple of links  which helped me to get the "updates" tab by using regedit

1. Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Wow6432Node > JavaSoft > Java
   Update > Policy".
2. Create a DWORD (32-bit) value and named it as
   "EnableJavaUpdate".
3. Set its value (value type - hex) to 1 to
   display the Update tab.  Set its value to 0 to hide the Update tab
   from the Java console.

Sources:
    http://ccm.net/faq/35020-java-the-update-tab-is-missing-from-the-java-control-panel
https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/68463-update-tab-missing-java-control-panel-version-8-update-11-64-bit.html

However, now when I click on "Update now" in the Updates tab, I get this error message "RuntimeException: Can not launch update check, jucheck.exe doesn't exist at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Java\Java Update\jucheck.exe

Should I be doing this another way?  Do I have to download the new version of java executable and install it in another location and then point CF to it? It seems like it shouldn't be this hard to update Java!!

Comment: Simply download the JDK, install to the path you want and point Coldfusion to use this Java install

Comment: Thanks @BernardDobler.  I know I could probably go that route but now that CF 2016 updates can be done directly through the coldfusion administrator, it feels so counter-intuitive to have to download and install another version of java to be able to install the updates.  Shouldn't the jre that's installed with CF just be able to update automatically too?